# Proof of lemma that function is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found this lemma in a book and decided to prove it:

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$. If there are functions $g : B \rightarrow A$ and $h: B \rightarrow A$ such tat $g(f(a)) = a$ for every $a \in A$ and $f(h(b)) = b$ for every $b \in B$, then f is bijective and $g = h = f^{-1}$

I have been able to prove that f is bijective as follows:

**Injection**: Let us assume that f is not injective. Then $b = f(a)$ and $b = f(a')$ and $a \neq a'$. But then $g(b) = a$ and $g(b) = a'$ - which is contradictory since g is a function and this goes against the rule of assignment. This means that f is injective.

**Surjection**: This was a bit simpler. For every $b \in B$ we have $b = f(h(b))$. Which means that f is surjective.

Which means that f is bijective and has an inverse function $f^{-1}$. But I can't prove why $g$ and $h$ both have to be the inverse function.

Comment: As a general rule, it's better practice to avoid contradiction if it doesn't reduce the complexity of the proof. In the case of the injection, we can just assume that $f(a)=f(a')$ and show that $a=a'$. The direct proof follows the same thought process, but is a little more elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have proved that $f:A\to B$ has an inverse $f^{-1}:B\to A$, then it follows very quickly that $g=h=f^{-1}$:
$$
\forall b\in B, g(b)=g(f(f^{-1}(b))\color{red}{=}f^{-1}(b)\implies g=f^{-1};\\
\forall b\in B, h(b)=f^{-1}(f(h(b))\color{red}{=}f^{-1}(b)\implies h=f^{-1}.
$$
The first equality in each line above uses the fact that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$ and the equalities highlighted in red use the given assumptions of $g$ and $h$.

Comment: This is an old question/answer, but thank you for writing it up!

Answer (score 0):

Let g and h be different then, but:
$$f(g(a))=a,f(h(a))=a\implies g(a)=h(a)\text{ by bijectivity of }f$$
*Contradiction.*

Comment: What justifies the statement that $f(g(a))=a$? We are given that $g(f(a))=a$.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic that's property of inverse function.

Comment: Yes, but we're trying to prove that $g$ is the inverse function. We can't assume.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic i think the op asks that g and h are inverse functions but why both of them are inverse function, i mean it needs to be proven that g=h

Comment: The OP proves that $f$ is invertible. The problem demands the proof that the inverse is in fact $g=h$ and the OP uses the same language of the problem to present the question. Furthermore, the OP gives no reference to any evidence that $g$ or $h$ is the inverse.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic it seems maybe that i misunderstood thanks